# ¿Error al crear un archivo.txt?

Tags: python, txt

Tengo un problema con este codigo, estoy creando un archivo .txt para posteriormente pasarlo a LaTex, sin embargo algunas lineas NO las escribe en el archivo.txt o las pone parcialmente y no tengo idea de por que. Aqui esta el codigo:

```
import re
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp

archivotxt="Pruebas3.txt"
texto= open(archivotxt,"w+") ## Reescribe todo el texto
TituloEjercicio="Ejercicio 01"
texto.write("\\text{\\huge {\\textbf {%s}}}\r"%(sp.latex(TituloEjercicio)))

x = sp.Symbol("x")
y = sp.Symbol("y")
z = sp.Symbol("z")
u = sp.Symbol("u")
v = sp.Symbol("v")
w = sp.Symbol("w")

xl = "x"
yl = "y"
zl = "z"
ul = "u"
vl = "v"
wl = "w"

e1=(1,-2,3)
e2=(-1,0,3)
e3=(5,4,-2)

x1=u
x2=v
x3=w
N=3


def pbaseco(e1,e2,e3,x1,x2,x3,N,archivotxt):
    texto = open(archivotxt,"w+")
    texto.write("\\text{Para obtener la base coordenada}\r")
    texto.write("\\text{Para obtener la base coordenada}\r")
    if N==3:
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j}+(%s)\\hat{k} \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(e1[0]),sp.latex(e1[1]),sp.latex(e1[2])))
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j}+(%s)\\hat{k} \r"%(sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(e2[0]),sp.latex(e2[1]),sp.latex(e2[2])))
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j}+(%s)\\hat{k} \r"%(sp.latex(x3),sp.latex(e3[0]),sp.latex(e3[1]),sp.latex(e3[2])))
        texto.write("\\text{En forma de matriz: }\r")
        TrM=Matrix([[e1[0], e1[1], e1[2]],[e2[0], e2[1], e2[2]],[e3[0], e3[1], e3[2]]])
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix}\\right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{i} \\\\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix}\\right] \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3),sp.latex(TrM)))
        #texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right]= \\left[\\begin{matrix} {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\end{matrix}\\right] \\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3),sp.latex(e1[0]),sp.latex(e1[1]),sp.latex(e1[2]),sp.latex(e2[0]),sp.latex(e2[1]),sp.latex(e2[2]),sp.latex(e3[0]),sp.latex(e3[1]),sp.latex(e3[2])))
        texto.write("\\text{De modo que la matriz de coordenadas inversa quedaria: }\r")
        ans=TrM.inv()
        #texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix} \\right]=\\left[\\begin{matrix} {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\end{matrix}\\right] \\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(ans[0]),sp.latex(ans[1]),sp.latex(ans[2]),sp.latex(ans[3]),sp.latex(ans[4]),sp.latex(ans[5]),sp.latex(ans[6]),sp.latex(ans[7]),sp.latex(ans[8]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3)))
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{i} \\\\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix}\\right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix}\\right]"%(sp.latex(ans),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3)))       
        texto.write("\\text{Entonces: }\r")
        texto.write("\\hat{i}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[0]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[1]),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(ans[2]),sp.latex(x3)))
        texto.write("\\hat{j}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[3]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[4]),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(ans[5]),sp.latex(x3)))
        texto.write("\\hat{k}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[6]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[7]),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(ans[8]),sp.latex(x3)))
    if N==2:
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j} \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(e1[0]),sp.latex(e1[1])))
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j} \r"%(sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(e2[0]),sp.latex(e2[1])))
        texto.write("\\text{En forma de matriz: }\r")
        TrM=Matrix([[e1[0], e1[1]],[e2[0], e2[1]]])
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(TrM)))
        texto.write("\\text{De modo que la matriz de coordenadas inversa quedaria: }\r")
        ans=TrM.inv()
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\end{matrix}\ \right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(ans),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2)))
        texto.write("\\text{Entonces: }\r")
        texto.write("\\hat{i}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[0]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[1]),sp.latex(x2)))
        texto.write("\\hat{j}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[2]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[3]),sp.latex(x2)))
    return ans

Resultado=pbaseco(e1,e2,e3,x1,x2,x3,N,archivotxt)

texto.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi tuve que escribirlo 2 veces pro que la primera no la escribe en el archivo de texto, pero si cambio el texto de la linea 36 un poco ya me da error por que escribe algo random, ni idea de por que.....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver deja el espacio en blanco, lo corri escribiendo solo la linea 36 y escribia "}". ¿Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema o por que esta ocurriendo?

Nota: Debe estar dentro de la funcion debido a que posteriormente lo llamare, tambien cambie el w+ por a+, pero no cambia en absolutamente nada.

Comment: Fijate que abres el archivo al principio del codigo y luego dentro de la función, y solo lo cierras una vez al final del codigo. Tal vez sería mejor pasarle el archivo abierto a la función, en vez del nombre del archivo, y asi evitas abrirlo dos veces.

Comment: Si alguna linea del codigo tira una excepción entre que abres el archivo y lo cierras puede que no se guarde correctamente. Para evitar eso puedes [abrir el archivo con *with*](https://python-docs-es.readthedocs.io/es/3.8/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Ya cerré el archivo de texto dentro de la propia función pero igual no cambia nada, la linea 36 sigue sin escribirse :(.

Comment: Si quito el "texto = open(archivotxt,"w+)"  de la función, todo queda de maravilla, pero el problema es que necesito que la función la tome de otro archivo, y si no defino a "texto" me va a marcar error. El problema supongo esta ahí en como escribir correctamente lo que esta dentro de una función llamada desde otro archivo.py Alguna idea?

Comment: Aparte de los problemas de abrir y cerrar archivo, estás usando `\r` como fin de línea, lo cual puede darte también problemas. Cámbialo por `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema ocurre porque abres el archivo dos veces. Cada vez que llamas a
`open` recibes un objeto que representa a un archivo y es independiente de
otro, aún si es abierto con el mismo nombre.

Para corregirlo, debes abrir el archivo una sola vez y pasarle a tu función
el objeto que representa el archivo. Luego de ejecutar la función, cierras el
archivo y los cambios deberían escribirse.

Para no cerrar el archivo explicitamente, se puede usar *with*.

Solucion propuesta:

```
import re
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp

archivotxt="Pruebas3.txt"
TituloEjercicio="Ejercicio 01"

x = sp.Symbol("x")
y = sp.Symbol("y")
z = sp.Symbol("z")
u = sp.Symbol("u")
v = sp.Symbol("v")
w = sp.Symbol("w")

xl = "x"
yl = "y"
zl = "z"
ul = "u"
vl = "v"
wl = "w"

e1=(1,-2,3)
e2=(-1,0,3)
e3=(5,4,-2)

x1=u
x2=v
x3=w
N=3

def pbaseco(e1,e2,e3,x1,x2,x3,N,texto):
    texto.write("\\text{Para obtener la base coordenada}\r")
    texto.write("\\text{Para obtener la base coordenada}\r")
    if N==3:
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j}+(%s)\\hat{k} \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(e1[0]),sp.latex(e1[1]),sp.latex(e1[2])))
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j}+(%s)\\hat{k} \r"%(sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(e2[0]),sp.latex(e2[1]),sp.latex(e2[2])))
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j}+(%s)\\hat{k} \r"%(sp.latex(x3),sp.latex(e3[0]),sp.latex(e3[1]),sp.latex(e3[2])))
        texto.write("\\text{En forma de matriz: }\r")
        TrM=Matrix([[e1[0], e1[1], e1[2]],[e2[0], e2[1], e2[2]],[e3[0], e3[1], e3[2]]])
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix}\\right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{i} \\\\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix}\\right] \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3),sp.latex(TrM)))
        #texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right]= \\left[\\begin{matrix} {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\end{matrix}\\right] \\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3),sp.latex(e1[0]),sp.latex(e1[1]),sp.latex(e1[2]),sp.latex(e2[0]),sp.latex(e2[1]),sp.latex(e2[2]),sp.latex(e3[0]),sp.latex(e3[1]),sp.latex(e3[2])))
        texto.write("\\text{De modo que la matriz de coordenadas inversa quedaria: }\r")
        ans=TrM.inv()
        #texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix} \\right]=\\left[\\begin{matrix} {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\\\ {%s} & {%s} & {%s}\\end{matrix}\\right] \\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(ans[0]),sp.latex(ans[1]),sp.latex(ans[2]),sp.latex(ans[3]),sp.latex(ans[4]),sp.latex(ans[5]),sp.latex(ans[6]),sp.latex(ans[7]),sp.latex(ans[8]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3)))
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{i} \\\\\\ \\hat{j} \\\\\\ \\hat{k} \\end{matrix}\\right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix}\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix}\\right]"%(sp.latex(ans),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(x3)))       
        texto.write("\\text{Entonces: }\r")
        texto.write("\\hat{i}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[0]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[1]),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(ans[2]),sp.latex(x3)))
        texto.write("\\hat{j}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[3]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[4]),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(ans[5]),sp.latex(x3)))
        texto.write("\\hat{k}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[6]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[7]),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(ans[8]),sp.latex(x3)))
    if N==2:
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j} \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(e1[0]),sp.latex(e1[1])))
        texto.write("\\hat{e}_{%s}=(%s)\\hat{i}+(%s)\\hat{j} \r"%(sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(e2[0]),sp.latex(e2[1])))
        texto.write("\\text{En forma de matriz: }\r")
        TrM=Matrix([[e1[0], e1[1]],[e2[0], e2[1]]])
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2),sp.latex(TrM)))
        texto.write("\\text{De modo que la matriz de coordenadas inversa quedaria: }\r")
        ans=TrM.inv()
        texto.write("\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{i} \\\\ \\hat{j} \\end{matrix}\ \right]={%s}\\left[\\begin{matrix} \\hat{e}_{%s} \\\\ \\hat{e}_{%s} \\end{matrix} \\right] \r"%(sp.latex(ans),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(x2)))
        texto.write("\\text{Entonces: }\r")
        texto.write("\\hat{i}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[0]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[1]),sp.latex(x2)))
        texto.write("\\hat{j}=(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s}+(%s)\\hat{e}_{%s} \r"%(sp.latex(ans[2]),sp.latex(x1),sp.latex(ans[3]),sp.latex(x2)))
    return ans

with open(archivotxt,"w") as texto:
    texto.write("\\text{\\huge {\\textbf {%s}}}\r"%(sp.latex(TituloEjercicio)))

    Resultado=pbaseco(e1,e2,e3,x1,x2,x3,N,texto)
```

Comment: Gracias, el detalle esta en que lo necesitaba dentro de la función por que voy a abrir múltiples funciones que provienen de otros archivos.py, y si no defino a "texto = open(archivotxt,"w+")" dentro de la propia función me va a dar error. Sin embargo si tiene razón el error es por que se abre 2 veces, entonces la solución es cerrarlo antes de abrir cualquier función, y dentro de la función abrirlo y cerrarlo. Quizá exista una solución mas fácil pero esta es la que me soluciono todo.